# Typing lag for remotely connected Ubuntu 22.04 Machine from Windows 10

Tags: remote-desktop, 22.04, remote, rdp

I will first of all start by telling that I am not an expert Linux user and most of the things I use on Linux are based on trial and error :)

I have an Ubuntu Machine with Ubuntu 22.04 which I aim to connect with my Windows 10 machine on the same (my university's) network. In order to connect the machine, I followed some online tutorials where I installed and enabled xdrp server on my ubuntu machine to use it remotely with my windows machine. using the following commands:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```

However, I was able to connect to the machine with the default Windows Remote Desktop option using the Ubuntu's built in Remote Desktop Sharing option (the one which we can search in the Settings) using the machine's ip address and the security password that needs to be input in Ubuntu for remote sharing.

All was working fine and the remote desktop connection was working like charm. Then the Ubuntu machine prompted to install some updates and restart the machine, which I did. After the restart, when I tried to remotely connect the machine with Windows, the Remote Desktop Screen took me to Xdrp username and password entry windows (meaning it was not going via tha default Ubuntu's remote sharing path but via XDRP) which eventually did not connect. I stopped, uninstalled and purged xdrp, using the following commands on terminal:

```
sudo systemctl stop xrdp
sudo apt-get remove xrdp
sudo apt-get purge xrdp
```

After that I was able to connect back to the machine using the default Windows and Ubuntu options. However, the problem now is that there is too much lag in (i) typing and in (ii) opening, closing and moving windows, that the connection is unusable. However, there is no lag at all in mouse movements on the desktop

The only solution I am now thinking is reinstalling Ubuntu on the machine. However, is there anything I can do to overcome this issue? I am not sure what has caused the issue, if its the new update or some settings change that happened when the connection got attempted via xdrp route?

Please help as it gives me sleepless nights now :D

Comment: We need more details about "*I followed some online tutorials where I installed and enabled xdrp*". What tutorials did you follow? What exactly did you install and how did you enable xrdp? Please [edit] your question to add details. I suggest to structure your long text block a bit using paragraphs, lists etc. in order to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Edited the post.

Comment: Judging by the fact that it is remote, I can come to the conclusion that it may be there because you aren't physically connected to it, and the keyboard has to broadcast to a distant system. There is naturally going to be a lag with this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But it was working absolutely fine (with no lag) before I restarted my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I'm facing a lag issue as well but I realised the issue is not with keyboard input but rather screen updates. Usually when I do something remotely, the screen doesn't update quick enough. A "hack" for me is to move the mouse cursor which seems to force a screen refresh for me

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 22.04 - recently ran into this issue
Typing in terminl does not update unless the mouse is moved.
fine using a VM on a windows host but using a real machine on the lan it is very bad.
solution was to switch to "Ubuntu on Xorg" at the login options.

Comment: As answered by @user1620828 the fix is: "solution was to switch to "Ubuntu on Xorg" at the login options" Thanks for posting the solution.